# css input corner triangle label with border radius

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I would like to create an triangle label inside input (text) element exactly like this: 
[image: input triangle corner with border radius]

What I managed to do so far is this: 
[image: input triangle corner without border radius]

How can I put this triangle **"under"** the input border to, let's just say, keep border radius from input cutting the edge of this triangle?

This is my code:

```
<div class="input">
   <label>email adress</label>
   <div class="note">
      <p>*</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email adress">
   </div>
</div>

.input {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: 100%;
}
.note > input {
   width: 515px;
   height: 48px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
   box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 1px lightgray;
   padding-left: 20px;
   color: #acacac;
   -webkit-color: #acacac;
   -moz-color: #acacac;
   -ms-color: #acacac;
   -o-color: #acacac;
   font-size: 16px;
   background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.50);
}

.note > input:focus {
   outline: none;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.note {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
.note:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   display: block;
   border-left: 35px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 35px solid transparent;
   border-top: 35px solid #0094bb;
}
```

I imagine there is no way to give border-radius to this triangle itself without losing its shape, am I right?

Comment: can you please  put your code using snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added position absolute for your P tag and postioned it in the corner.
The border radius is achieved by adding a border radius to your .note wrapper and setting overflow:hidden.

```css
.note > input {
   width: 515px;
   height: 48px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
   box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 1px lightgray;
   padding-left: 20px;
   color: #acacac;
   -webkit-color: #acacac;
   -moz-color: #acacac;
   -ms-color: #acacac;
   -o-color: #acacac;
   font-size: 16px;
   background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.50);
}

.note > input:focus {
   outline: none;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.note {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 5px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.note:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   display: block;
   border-left: 35px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 35px solid transparent;
   border-top: 35px solid #0094bb;
   z-index:0;
   
}
.note p{
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  color:white;
  z-index:1;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

label { 
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
   <label>email address</label>
   <div class="note">
      <p>*</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email adress">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: glad to help! Please accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider declaring the *pseudo-element* to a nested element of `.note` instead.

This will allow you to specify the required `border-radius` property on the containing element rather than the *pseudo-element*. With an `overflow: hidden` rule declared on this new containing element in addition, the top-right corner of the *pseudo-element* will be "cut-off" from view, conveying the impression that this is an element nested within the input field.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.note > input {
   width: 515px;
   height: 48px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
   box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 1px lightgray;
   padding-left: 20px;
   color: #acacac;
   -webkit-color: #acacac;
   -moz-color: #acacac;
   -ms-color: #acacac;
   -o-color: #acacac;
   font-size: 16px;
   background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.50);
}

.note > input:focus {
   outline: none;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.note {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}

/* additional */
.note .required {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: right;
}

.note .required:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 35px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 35px solid transparent;
    border-top: 35px solid #0094bb;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
   <label>email adress</label>
   <div class="note">
      <span class="required">*</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email adress">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest i could get with your solution. But I found other ways you're satisfied with this okay...

```css
.note > input {
   width: 515px;
   height: 48px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #7d7d7d;
   box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 1px lightgray;
   padding-left: 20px;
   color: #acacac;
   -webkit-color: #acacac;
   -moz-color: #acacac;
   -ms-color: #acacac;
   -o-color: #acacac;
   font-size: 16px;
   background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.50);
}

.note > input:focus {
   outline: none;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.note {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
.note:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   display: block;
   line-height: 48px;
   text-align: top;
   border-left: 35px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 35px solid transparent;
   border-top: 35px solid #0094bb;
}
.note::before {
   content: "*";
   position: absolute;
   right: 7px;
   z-index: 1;
   top: 5px;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
   <label>email adress</label>
   <div class="note">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email adress">
   </div>
</div>
```